# Мониторинг прораммы

Tags: linux, многопоточность, asp.net-mvc

Есть программа (сайт) `.net Framework 4.6.1`. Сайт работает на `Debian`(`apache2`+`mono`). В какой-то момент (раз в 17-24 часа) запускаются какие-то треды (потоки) и залипают (без вывода ошибок). Т е сайт и дальше продолжает корректно отрабатывать, но если вызвать `htop`, то я увижу у 2х ядер (из 2х) цп загружено на 100% постоянно и параллельно работающие потоки. Многопоточность в своем коде не юзаю, но подозреваю что это делают либы "под капотом".

Соль в том, что проблему в моем коде не нахожу. Грешу на какую-то из библиотек, но увы проверить не могу, т к их многовато.

Вопрос: как можно промониторить какой поток, чем запущен, что выпоняет ну или что-то, что даст понять где бок?

Еще момент...в `linux` не силен...мб есть утилита какая-нибудь, которая помочь сможет. Пробовал через `strace` - но ничего не дало (вижу что что-то выполняется, но понять не могу что именно)

Comment: Что у вас в `top`? первые 10 строчек. (это команда)

Answer (score 1):

> как можно промониторить какой поток, чем запущен

Для таких задач существует специальная утилита *ps*. У неё два синтаксиса параметров (исторически так сложилось) Привожу оба эквивалентных варианта.

Распечатать дерево процессов (кто кого запустил):

```
      ps -ejH
      ps axjf
```

Получить информацию о тредах:

```
      ps -eLf
      ps axms
```